# How can I save value of dynamic variable in Postman?

Tags: postman

Postman allows to generate random dummy data by using [pre-defined variables](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables-list/), on example this one would be replaced by random company name:

`{{$randomCompanyName}}`

Using pre-defined variables multiple times return different values per request.

The question is how to save once generated value to the variable for further usage on example in tests, something like(it doesn't work):

`pm.variables.set("company", {{$randomCompanyName}});`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.replaceIn()` function with that `{{...}}` syntax in the sandbox.

`pm.globals.set("company", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomCompanyName}}'));`

I've used a `global` variable to store the value as you would want to use it again. You could also use either the `environment` or `collectionVariables` scope to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But where did you find the information about `.replaceIn()`? Can't find it in official postman docs...

Comment: I officially work for them :) I'll make sure that's updated in the doc.